# Polygons and lines not drawing correctly (in QGIS from PostGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis

I load osm file into postgresql and then i connect to the database with qgis t to plot it and  i see this

[image: this]

it happens to whatever file i import to the database, even when i download it from http://metro.teczno.com/
i also get the same result when i plot the lines but i did not include them in the screenshot just to be clearer [ i can provide one if asked ]...points are fine...

some relevant info that might be helpful

xubuntu 12.04
postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1

steps:

```
osm=#create extension postgis;
osm=#\i /usr/share/postgresql/9.3/contrib/postgis-2.1/legacy.sql
osm=#\i /usr/share/postgresql/9.3/contrib/postgis-2.1/legacy_gist.sql
```

then i simply load the osm file with

```
postgres@desk: osm2pgsql -U postgres  -d  osm  -S /usr/share/osm2pgsql/default.style mapFile.osm
```

output seems fine (at least to me)

```
Using projection SRS 900913 (Spherical Mercator)
Setting up table: planet_osm_point
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_point_tmp" does not exist, skipping
Setting up table: planet_osm_line
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_line_tmp" does not exist, skipping
Setting up table: planet_osm_polygon
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_polygon_tmp" does not exist, skipping
Setting up table: planet_osm_roads
NOTICE:  table "planet_osm_roads_tmp" does not exist, skipping
Mid: Ram, scale=100

!! You are running this on 32bit system, so at most
!! 3GB of RAM can be used. If you encounter unexpected
!! exceptions during import, you should try running in slim
!! mode using parameter -s.

Reading in file: mapFile.osm
Processing: Node(13k) Way(2k) Relation(258)  parse time: 1s

Node stats: total(13746), max(2147483647)
Way stats: total(2090), max(267296233)
Relation stats: total(258), max(3555834)

Writing way (2k)

Writing relation (258)
Committing transaction for planet_osm_line
Committing transaction for planet_osm_point
Committing transaction for planet_osm_roads
Sorting data and creating indexes for planet_osm_line
Committing transaction for planet_osm_polygon
Sorting data and creating indexes for planet_osm_point
Sorting data and creating indexes for planet_osm_roads
Sorting data and creating indexes for planet_osm_polygon
Completed planet_osm_roads
Completed planet_osm_line
Completed planet_osm_polygon
Completed planet_osm_point
```

Can someone explain why this might happen?

As far as i can see, some polygons, if not all, polygons are not correctly parsed and closed and include a point that is located at the center of the plot(?)

I am really new to this and my first goal is just to correctly load an osm file into a postgis database and just display it correctly (i actually want to render it with python mapnik, but that will follow if/when this is solved).

Comment: That's awesome, it looks like a front view of some kind of ancient-future-themed mega-spaceship-city. (Yeah, helpful and on topic, as always).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to use a recent version of osm2pgsql.

Openstreetmap node numbers have crossed the 2^31 bit boundary for integers, which needed to rewrite almost all software dealing with node numbers. Your max node is just beyond the limit, so i assume newer points get mistreated into a single point at 0°/0° in the Atlantic Ocean.

Comment: OP here..if anyone has similar issues, as Andre Joost noted, use the **latest** osm2pgsql(currently 0.85) from git and create hstore extension in you db if you want all the data to be correctly imported